# setting up rel="next" javascript ajax <a>

Tags: seo

I have a  tag (show more) that when user clicks it loads the next 10 results onto what is already there.
I looked around to make this seo friendly but all this talks about is ..
how can i make my  relevant for seo next page (really showing more instead of next)

Comment: So you're loading the next 10 with ajax?

Comment: that is correct.. and adding to the existing list

Answer (score 0):

Rather than load with ajax, why not just hide everything after the first 10 and have the next tag *show* the next 10. See following example.

```
  <style>
        .hide{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>


    <div id='contain'>

        <?php
            //Not sure what you are loading but this is a dummy loop done in PHP
            $i=0;
            while($i<101){
                //Set the class based on the result. If greater than 10 then hide this result.
                $class = ($i<10 ? "result" : "result hide");

                echo"<div class='$class'>
                        <p>MY CONTENT</p>
                    </div>";
                $i++;
            }
        ?>

    </div>

    <a href='#' id='showMore'>Show 10 More</a>


    <script>
        $('#showMore').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var i = 0;
            $('.hide').each(function(){
                if(i<10){
                    $(this).removeClass('hide');
                }
                else{
                    return;
                }
                i++;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

That is the only way I can think of solving the problem. I understand ajax is being used to speed up the query.

Comment: Yeah I know, that's the only way I can think of that would be able to achieve that result though... Please dont vote down my answer for actually providing a workable solution.